# HOW to FC SAN cord compatibility? Cisco FC switch (DS-X9448-768K9) and HP Proliant servers (360 g6, g7, 380 g8), with HP SN1100E 16Gbps HBA

Tags: cisco, hp, san, fibrechannel

I have obtained a couple of Cisco Fibre Channel switches (DS-X9448-768K9) in the 9700 MDS, which this being my first foray into constructing a SAN with a ZFS FreeBSD server, which I have ebay 'good deals' in the form of 4 HP Proliant servers (360 g6, g7, 380 g8) and disk shelves (M6710), but HP's cords are a different form than the usual SFP+ connection, I gather. I'm wondering, Given a SN1100E 16Gbps HBA, HOW to achieve cord compatibility?

Both are SFP+! Do I need to buy a transceiver? A compatible cord? Do you specify compatability with the client side or switch side? I'm stymied by my own ignorance.

I don't want over copper, and I don't want over ethernet. What I'd like best is something that converts HP's port to Cisco's port. Thank you for taking the time to read through my woes.

Comment: If you're not planning to use DACs you'll need to get compatible SFP transceivers and LC patch cables.

Comment: What I don't understand is the speed drop of copper cables. 16 Gb/s of HBA/Switch speeds drops down to 10Gb/s just for using the SFP+ copper. Am I wrong in that?

Comment: You need to use 16GFC SFP modules. SFP+ modules for Ethernet won't take that speed, they only support 8GFC. Copper or fiber doesn't matter.